# UIScrollView ContentSize Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Im a little bit confused by the `contentSize` property in `UIScrollView`. I have an image in my scrollView that I'm zooming and panning. I have been playing around with different values for `contentSize`, but it seems to me that it doesn't really matter what values I enter, the `contentSize` is always set to the size of the image. Ive noted that this only happens when I have performed a zoom. Before I zoom, the contentSize maintains the values that I set, but after zooming, `contentSize` sets itself to the size of the image.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: How are you adding the image to the scrollview?

Comment: @StephenAshley.developer [self.scrollView addSubview:image]

Comment: are you returning the UIImageView in the viewForZooming delegate method?

Comment: yes - otherwise how would I get any zooming at all. My scrollView works just fine, I can zoom my image etc, Im just trying to understand this strange property of contentSize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is interesting. According to printout of the following `- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`
contentSize is actually `scrollview.frame.size` x `scrollview.zoomScale`.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if ([self.scrollView zoomScale] < 1.0)[self.scrollView setZoomScale:1.0];

    NSLog (@"didZoom: ZoomScale: %.2f; ContentSize: %@; ScrollView: %@", self.scrollView.zoomScale, NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.contentSize),NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.frame.size));
}
```

Two lines of the prinout:

didZoom: ZoomScale: 1.76; ContentSize: {1798.02, 1208.05}; ScrollView: {1024, 688}

didZoom: ZoomScale: 1.50; ContentSize: {1537.94, 1033.3}; ScrollView: {1024, 688}

Didn't find this 'feature' in documentation.

**Edit**: tried also following:

```
-(void) manualSettingOfContentSizeAndZoomScale

{
    NSLog (@"A: ZoomScale: %.2f; ContentSize: %@; ScrollView: %@", self.scrollView.zoomScale, NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.contentSize),NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.frame.size));

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1800.0,1200.0);

    NSLog (@"B: ZoomScale: %.2f; ContentSize: %@; ScrollView: %@", self.scrollView.zoomScale, NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.contentSize),NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.frame.size));

    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.8;

    NSLog (@"C: ZoomScale: %.2f; ContentSize: %@; ScrollView: %@", self.scrollView.zoomScale, NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.contentSize),NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.frame.size));

    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    NSLog (@"D: ZoomScale: %.2f; ContentSize: %@; ScrollView: %@", self.scrollView.zoomScale, NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.contentSize),NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.frame.size));
}
```

The result were:

A: ZoomScale: 1.00; ContentSize: {0, 0}; ScrollView: {1024, 688}

B: ZoomScale: 1.00; ContentSize: {1800, 1200}; ScrollView: {1024, 688}

C: ZoomScale: 1.80; ContentSize: {1843.2, 1238.4}; ScrollView: {1024, 688}

D: ZoomScale: 1.80; ContentSize: {1024, 688}; ScrollView: {1024, 688}

A: OK, it's documented that default contentSize is `CGSizeZero` (though `scrollView` is normally showing it's content
at zoomScale 1.0

B: after setting `contentSize` `zoomScale` didn't change, neither did appearance of `scrollView`

C: after setting `zoomScale` `contentSize` and appearance changed accordingly

D: after resetting `contentSize` nothing changed - `contentSize` as a property did change but didn't affect the appearence

Conclusion: use `zoomScale` for setting the appearance of `scrollView`'s content

If memory serves me right contentSize is actually important for scrolling `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`. It is quite a complex object, so maybe everything isn't connected just as one might think or want.

Comment: interesting observation. If you set contentSize to different values (e.g. in viewDidLoad), does this relationship still hold? i.e. does the content size keep getting reset to scrollView frame*zoom?

Comment: no, see edit. it holds if you set zoomScale. I think (don't hold me for this) that contentSize is intended more for paging & scrolling than for zoom - while zooming you can use it as an information to calculate something, but you (looks like) can't zoom by simply setting conten't size. Seems o.k. since setting improper contentSize would affect scale ratio.

Comment: thats for the testing - very interesting. How do you think this works with my image? To get the behaviour I am seeing, it would mean that the scrollView's contentSize (or its frame, as it now appears) is changing to match the image size - this doesnt seem right. I'll check my autoScaling etc, but im pretty sure its all off for my scrollView.

Comment: i think you should calculate desired zoomScale (= desiredContentWidth/originalContentWidth), set it, and check if results are what you expect.

Comment: From my testing, I find it that contentSize is always equal to view which returned from `viewForZooming` * zoomScale. If you return nil from `viewForZooming`, contentSize if equal to size you set manually.